# How to configure CLion to insert GCC pragmas instead of clang pragmas?

Tags: clion

CLion detects "Unused import statement" in a cpp file. When I select "Suppress UnusedImportStatement for file" CLion inserts:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "UnusedImportStatement"

....

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

How do I configure CLion to generate these pragmas targeting GCC instead of clang?

Comment: This is not implemented yet.